# Disk full error, however 4GB/97GB remains

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

I have 4GB remaining on my partition, but I get a disk full error.

Ubuntu Disks program:
`Size: 97 GB — 4.7 GB free (95.2% full)`

`df` command:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1945292        0   1945292   0% /dev
tmpfs             394692     2132    392560   1% /run
/dev/sda8       92856968 88268000         0 100% /
tmpfs            1973456    45584   1927872   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1973456        0   1973456   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop2         58752    58752         0 100% /snap/discord/112
/dev/loop0         56320    56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop4         11648    11648         0 100% /snap/glade/231
/dev/loop3         58880    58880         0 100% /snap/discord/115
/dev/loop5        165376   165376         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop6        166784   166784         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop7        261760   261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop8        223232   223232         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop9         63616    63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop10       118912   118912         0 100% /snap/icloud-for-linux/166
/dev/loop11       185472   185472         0 100% /snap/obs-studio/1139
/dev/loop13        44288    44288         0 100% /snap/snap-store/415
/dev/loop12       185472   185472         0 100% /snap/obs-studio/1141
/dev/loop16        31104    31104         0 100% /snap/snapd/9279
/dev/loop17       297472   297472         0 100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/sda2         262144    38400    223744  15% /boot/efi
/dev/loop18        31744    31744         0 100% /snap/snapd/9607
tmpfs             394688       44    394644   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop15        51968    51968         0 100% /snap/snap-store/481
/dev/sdd1        7847952       16   7847936   1% /media/[username here]/A FAT32 DISK
```

`df -i` command:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            486323    697  485626    1% /dev
tmpfs           493364   1304  492060    1% /run
/dev/sda8      5931008 723915 5207093   13% /
tmpfs           493364    159  493205    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           493364      6  493358    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           493364     18  493346    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       10775  10775       0  100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop2         288    288       0  100% /snap/discord/112
/dev/loop0       10756  10756       0  100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop4        1465   1465       0  100% /snap/glade/231
/dev/loop3         290    290       0  100% /snap/discord/115
/dev/loop5       27798  27798       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop6       27807  27807       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop7       24339  24339       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop8       18513  18513       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop9       62342  62342       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop10       3173   3173       0  100% /snap/icloud-for-linux/166
/dev/loop11       7221   7221       0  100% /snap/obs-studio/1139
/dev/loop13      15358  15358       0  100% /snap/snap-store/415
/dev/loop12       7221   7221       0  100% /snap/obs-studio/1141
/dev/loop16        472    472       0  100% /snap/snapd/9279
/dev/loop17      51155  51155       0  100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/sda2            0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop18        472    472       0  100% /snap/snapd/9607
tmpfs           493364     99  493265    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop15      15843  15843       0  100% /snap/snap-store/481
/dev/sdd1            0      0       0     - /media/[username here]/A FAT32 DISK
```

Note on `/` that it says 92856968 bytes capacity: 88268000 bytes used, but 0 available?? what??
I have a 512GB disk but it's currently being erased.

Comment: No matter how you figure it, 4G or not, it's not enough to keep /tmp and /var happy... so backup/delete some stuff... or re-partition your disk.

Comment: Once my 512G disk wipes I'll move everything onto it. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 4G are the reserved blocks for use by privileged processes.  The default is 5% of the total filesystem.  See the man page for tune2fs to change this percentage:

man tune2fs
...
-m reserved-blocks-percentage
Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged processes.   Reserving some number of filesystem blocks for use
by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to  continue  to  function
correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem.  Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is
5%.